# How to use a UITextField in today extension in xcode 6?

Tags: xcode6, today-extension

I have created an extension for notification center and I wanna get some text inputs from the user. There is no problem with adding and interacting with the text fields. but when the text field gets focus keyboard will appear under the notification center. so. How can I fix this problem?!!!

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to use text fields in widgets, I read about a widget for notes that created it's own keyboard on the Notification Center (It probably had to use it's own because of what you're describing) and it was pulled from the store.

Comment: i think it is the only way to create a keyboard in the widget it self. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyboard will never appear, because using the keyboard is not supported in today extensions. Apple's [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH11-SW1) notes that

> In particular, note that iOS widgets don’t support keyboard entry.

You can use buttons but you can't get iOS to display a keyboard.